# Creating a Form2 in C# and editing it

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, solution-explorer

So I'm very, very new to C#, and relatively new to programming. I decided to learn by writing a program for my niece, but I'm having a bit of an issue trying to understand how I can manage my "Form2" using the visual designer in VS 2010.

The code I have so far doesn't have a problem running in debug, and the form is launched fine, but I can't find it in the solution explorer. This, I'm sure, has a really simple solution, and I feel stupid for asking it, but I can't find it on Google, or maybe I just don't know how to phrase the question.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void azbuka_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 azbukatest = new Form2();
            azbukatest.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution explorer shows files, while you have your Form2 defined in the same file where Form1 is located. If you want it to be in another file, you'd better add a new windows form to solution using "Add new item" command.

Comment: @Alexander: you can post the comment as an answer. This way if it IS the answer, it can be marked as the solution for his question.

Comment: Click on the form in Solution Explorer and press F7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you defined the second form in the same class as the first, rather than making another full form.  If you want the full designer, create a new form using the `Add` button within the project:

[image]

This way visual studio will take care of all the extra details that allow you to utilize the designer and many other perks.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this walkthrough. Next time search and then post questions. This is basic stuff and you can easily find tutorials/walkthroughs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd492132.aspx

Comment: I did search, as I said in my original post, I was unable to find it, or properly phrase the question.

Answer (score 0):

C# winforms has two components to it, a Designer and Code Behind.

What you've written here is just the code behind, which holds logic, events etc.

The visual form is the designer which holds the UI elements like buttons and textboxes.

Try adding a form using the Visual Studio menus (Add-> New -> Form) in your project, and it will add the dependant files.

Also, if you create a new class, it doesn't come up in the solution explorer as a new file automatically, try looking at the "Class View".

Answer (score 0):

If you want a form generated that you can access in Solution Explorer you should right click on the project name and click **Add-> New Item** and select Windows Form from there.

This will create a form you can edit in the IDE. Remember to remove

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {

    }
}
```

before doing this if you want it to be called **Form2** (since creating the form via **Add Item** will create this code for you